# How to use widgets.Datetime() from ipywidgets in jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
widgets.Datetime()
```

When i run above code in Jupyter Notebook i get 
output as `<ipywidgets.widgets.trait_types.Datetime at 0x7f7b86459e48>`

What is the correct way of using `widgets.Datetime()`

Comment: Could you add more context to your question? It is unclear what you are expecting.

Answer (score 2):

Do you actually want the `DateTimePicker`?

```python
import ipywidgets
ipywidgets.Datepicker()
```

Otherwise it's not that clear what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself asking the same so here it is :

**ipywidgets.Datetime() isn't actually a widget but a ["trait type holding a python data object"](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/blob/d680673ad8d43be794d47d84c928cc0e04db8430/ipywidgets/widgets/trait_types.py#L53)**

The Date**time**Picker will be available in [ipywidgets 8.0](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/pull/2715) and hasn't been released yet.

Meanwhile if you need a date **and time** picker you might want to use [ipydatetime](https://ipydatetime.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/introduction.html) with a look at the current [issues](https://github.com/vidartf/ipydatetime/issues) first.

```py
import ipydatetime
import ipywidgets
import datetime

datetime_picker = ipydatetime.DatetimePicker()
datetime_picker
```